# UICollectionView changing layout selected item and frame/constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've got a collection view where I'm dynamically changing between a layout that looks like a UITableView and a layout that looks sort of like the TimeMachine like carousel that I'm calling "SwipeLayout" (which doesn't do swiping right now, but it will eventually).

BTW, The entire project is here: https://github.com/SuperTango/CollectionViewLayoutSwitching.  Under the master branch with tag "initial_question"

The initial layout is the table layout, when an item is tapped, I change the layout to the "SwipeLayout" with animation (and back again). In my ViewController, I have:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("index Path chosen: \(indexPath)")
    changeLayoutTapped(self)
}

@IBAction func changeLayoutTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout == tableLayout) {
        self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(swipeLayout, animated: true)
        self.mode = Mode.Swipe
    } else {
        self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(tableLayout, animated: true)
        self.mode = Mode.Table
    }
}
```

The code for the SwipeLayout is a bit long, so I don't want to put it in this SO question, but here's a link to it: https://github.com/SuperTango/CollectionViewLayoutSwitching/blob/initial_question/CollectionViewLayouts/SwipeLayout.swift

Here's what the transition currently looks like:

[image: transition starting at 0 at full speed]

For the most part, it looks good.  However, if we start the tap on an element other than zero, this happens:

[image: transition starting at 4 at full speed]

I can't figure out why it goes through the transition and then snaps back to showing the 0 element first.

here's what it looks like after turning on slow transitions in the sim:

[image: transition starting at 4 at slow speed]

I've tried setting the selected element on the collection view like so:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("index Path chosen: \(indexPath)")
    self.swipeLayout.startingItemIndex = indexPath.item
    changeLayoutTapped(self)
}
```

But no luck there.

Any ideas?

Extra bonus if someone can tell me how to get the contents (the numbers inside) to stay centered in the middle of the view during the entire transition.

Thanks.